# Android RelativeLayout with wrap_content truncates some children

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-xml

I have a RelativeLayout whose width/height is set to wrap_content. However, the button in the bottom right is truncated on its lower side.
Changing the RelativeLayout's paddingBottom doesn't help, neither does adding a marginBottom to the button.

Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/sign_up_phase_enteraddress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:background="#ff6aa639"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sign_up_signuphere"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
        android:text="@string/sign_up_signuphere"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sign_up_emaillabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/sign_up_signuphere"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/sign_up_signuphere"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/sign_up_email"
        android:text="@string/sign_up_emailaddress"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/sign_up_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="46dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/sign_up_signuphere"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sign_up_emaillabel"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >

        <requestFocus />

    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sign_up_signup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/sign_up_haveaccount"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/sign_up_email"
        android:layout_below="@id/sign_up_email"
        android:text="@string/sign_up_signup" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sign_up_haveaccount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/sign_up_emaillabel"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/sign_up_email"
        android:text="@string/sign_up_haveaccount"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

...and this is what it looks like in the emulator:
[image: button truncated]

Any thoughts on how I can get the bottom of my button to show?
TIA!

Comment: maybe it helps if You put Your sign_up_sign_up button and Your sign_up_haveaccount textView inside a horizontal orientated LinearLayout and specifiy android:layout_below="@id/sign_up_email" for this linear layout. If You do this, don´t forget to set layout_weight="1" for both (button and textView)

Comment: Thanks. I agree, that would probably work. However I don't see any reason why it shouldn't be working without that, using just the RelativeLayout? I'd prefer not to have to add extra layouts which (should be) unnecessary as that affects performance/memory etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My fast idea is to set button bottom border to height of text on the left by using xml code

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sign_up_haveaccount"
```

because you've setted `layout_below` option already. However your xml code is quite not proper :) I will try write here better xml code for you, later.

---

Well, I found your problem. And I was searching for solution.
I setted for textview new padding bottom because button was aligned to this textview basline. I know that it could be a nice hack but I coudln't find andy good way to handle it :)

According to your layout I changed behaviour for edittext to make it stretchable. Also I grouped all elements into 3 groups. Each one per row to make it more readable.

Also do not forget that first 2 lines about xmls.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/sign_up_phase_enteraddress"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="#ff6aa639"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp" >

<!-- 1 row -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/row1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="29dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sign_up_signuphere"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sign_up_signuphere"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- 2 row -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/row2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/row1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sign_up_emaillabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/sign_up_email"
        android:text="@string/sign_up_emailaddress"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/sign_up_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sign_up_emaillabel"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- 3 row -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/row3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/row2" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sign_up_haveaccount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:text="@string/sign_up_haveaccount"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sign_up_signup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/sign_up_haveaccount"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/sign_up_signup" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! That does cause the button to be shown correctly (not snipped) but I did want the button and "I already have an account" text to be aligned by baseline - it looks much neater that way.

Comment: Really interested to hear how the XML can be improved BTW. If you do get a chance to do that, it would be massively, massively appreciated as I'm still learning Android :)

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked perfectly! Really appreciate your time & energy - words cannot describe how much you rock :)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of your padding , you have given 10 dp padding in bottom and your button view doesn't have enough space.Remove padding and check it .