# Android RelativeLayout with wrap_content too small to fit children

Tags: android-layout, android-relativelayout, android, android-xml

Here is a simple `RelativeLayout` with 4 controls arranged in a tabular format.
When displayed, the `confirmpassword` box is clipped at the bottom. It's as if "`wrap_content`" is not correctly calculating the height of the children. Any ideas?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >  
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/passwordlabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:text="Password"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/passwordlabel"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/confirmpassword"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/passwordlabel"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/confirmpasslabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/passwordlabel"
        android:layout_below="@id/passwordlabel"
        android:text="Confirm Password"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/confirmpassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/confirmpasslabel"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/confirmpasslabel"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: RelativeLayout in emulator]

I have tried adding padding and/or margins to both of the bottom controls which has no effect (and strikes me as a hack anyway).

NB:- I had a similar problem [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298976/android-relativelayout-with-wrap-content-truncates-some-children) which a kindly soul solved essentially by splitting apart the RelativeLayout. I don't think that's possible here (it *may* be) but I'm concerned I'm either doing something completely wrong, or the `RelativeLayout` has a massive bug which seems under-documented.

Anyone able to shed light on this? TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does seem like a bit of a bug. I couldn't get it to work properly (without changing it somehow) with a `RelativeLayout` - something with the margins was throwing it off.

As a workaround, try a `TableLayout`:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="34dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/passwordlabel"
            android:text="Password"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="34dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/confirmpasslabel"
            android:text="Confirm Password"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/confirmpassword"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Ken. Looks like the way to go... but I'm still confused as to why the RelativeLayout doesn't work. It strikes me as a really basic bug and it's odd that there appears to be no mention of it!